# Web-scoped Feature falsely activated during Visual Studio deployment

Tags: 2010, deployment, feature, feature-activation

In Visual Studio I have a solution containing two features with their Scope set to "Web". These two features work as expected but the only thing that is going "wrong" is that they are activated when I deploy the solution. This shouldn't be happening since I set the property "Activate On Default" to "False.

At first I thought this was my fault since the features had already been installed when I set those properties to false. Then I deactivated and uninstalled both features (succesfully) to try again but upon deployment they are still activated.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or how I can solve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Activate On Default only works when the feature scope is set to Farm or Web Application.

[Here's a blog with a solution.](http://devramblings.wordpress.com/2011/03/23/activate-on-default/)

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that Visual Studio is doing the activation for you. The Visual Studio behavior is controlled via the "Active Deployment Configuration." There is a configuration named "No Activation" that will only deploy the solution, allowing you to activate as needed.